# Обложка и переплет

Tags: лексика

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, значение слов "обложка" и "переплет".

О слове "обложка" мы можем прочитать в Кратком толковом словаре по полиграфии следующее: *"Бумажная иллюстрированная или текстовая покрышка издания, предохраняющая его страницы от разрушения и загрязнения, содержит ряд выходных сведений, является также элементом внешнего оформления".* В словаре Ушакова о той же лексеме: *"Бумажная обертка, покрышка, в которую переплетается книга, тетрадь (в отличие от твердого переплета). Книга в нарядной обложке. Книги выпускают в обложках и в переплетах".* Правильно ли я понимаю, что как полиграфический термин слово "обложка" означает страницы книги с выходными данными, а как единица общего словоупотребления служит обозначением внешнего покрытия издания, изготовленного из бумаги? Если в соответствии со сказанным в Толковом словаре Ушакова "обложка" - это фактически мягкий переплет, а переплет может быть как мягким, так и твердым, то мягкий переплет = обложка. Являются ли эти рассуждения достаточным основанием для того, чтобы назвать обложку переплетом, а переплет - обложкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы совершенно правы: обложка- это мягкий переплёт. Но разница всё же есть.

Обложка, в традиционном понимании этого слова,— это бумажное покрытие книжного блока (то есть комплекта скрепленных между собой листов книги). Строение такой обложки несложно — она представляет собой лист бумаги, который охватывает книжный блок спереди, сзади и со стороны корешка. Те части обложки, которые прикрывают блок спереди и сзади, называются ее сторонками, а та часть ее, которая соответствует корешку блока и скреплена с ним,— корешком обложки.
Прочность чисто бумажной обложки может быть увеличена также припрессовкой к ней прозрачной синтетической пленки или лакировкой. Разработаны и более прочные клеи для скрепления обложки с книжным блоком. Прочность издания в обложке зависит и от способа ее скрепления с книжным блоком, причем сама конструкция обложки может несколько усложняться.

Переплет прочнее обложки,это переплетная крышка, он имеет более сложную конструкцию, чем обложка. Обычно крышка состоит из нескольких деталей: двух сторонок, корешка, наружного материала для оклейки сторонок (или всей крышки) и отстава — полоски плотной бумаги или тонкого картона, которая наклеивается на корешок крышки с оборотной стороны (отстав увеличивает прочность и упругость корешка); переплетная крышка может быть и цельной, но это редкость.

Comment: То есть мы не можем, например, назвать прочное покрытие издания обложкой исходя из того, что обложка - это разновидность переплета, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Видимо, нет.Обложку переплётом (мягким)назвать можно, она обложила книгу и соединилась с книгой, т.е.переплелась. А вот твёрдый переплёт - не только обложка, но и оклейка с двух сторон + отстав. Именно отстав является главной составляющей переплёта, удерживающей книгу от распадения на отдельные блоки страниц, а сама обложка - только крышка, мягкая или твёрдая.Просто в речи пропускается слово "твёрдый", остаётся только "переплёт".Правильнее было бы говорить "мягкий переплёт","твёрдый переплёт".